# jmediaelement: no jwplayer fallback IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, jwplayer

I'm using jmediaelement to provide jquery-ui styled controls for video. Works in all browsers, including, with jplayer fallback, Firefox and IE9, and IE8, when the content is inside a jquery ui dialog. But for some reason on page loads with IE8 the jplayer swf object isn't even injected into the page...

This is the markup in the page:

```
<div class="media-player large" style="width:600px;height:490px;">
  <video poster="http://pathfinder.remote-learner.net/theme/prepworks_formfactor/media/prepworks_logo_poster.png" preload="auto" controls="controls" width="600" height="450">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://pathfinder.remote-learner.net/theme/prepworks_formfactor/media/InteractiveMath1e.mp4"></source>
    <a href="http://pathfinder.remote-learner.net/theme/prepworks_formfactor/media/InteractiveMath1e.mp4">Vid for ipad safari</a>
  </video>
</div>
```

I'm loading jQuery, jquery ui, jmediaelement's mm.full.min.js and jmeEmbedControls.js in the page footer. player.swf is available in the same dir. In a subsequent script, I'm calling embedControls on any video elements in the page:

```
jQuery('div.media-player').jmeEmbedControls({ 
  mediaControls: {dynamicTimeslider: false,timeSliderAdjust: -1},
   embed:{ 
    jwPlayer: {// Set the path for the player.swf file (depends on a var called jsThemeDir being printed into the <head> from /layouts/general.php
     path: jsThemeDir + 'javascript/player.swf',
     plugins: { jmefs: jsThemeDir + 'javascript/jmefs.swf' }
    }   
   }   
});
```

I have no idea even what to try here. I tried adding jme's debug js file, but get nothing useful from it in IE8. Loading in FF it just prints "everything looks ok" in console. When I call jmeEmbedControls() from the console it just adds another set of unstyled controls below the original. No jwplayer. No styling.

Weirder yet, when I put the same markup that does not work in the page into a jquery ui dialog(), init the modal dialog, and make the same call to jmeEmbedControls, the video inside the dialog is skinned with jwplayer and plays (css is a little off, but it plays fine).

What am I missing? What should I be looking for? Why would code in the original page load not be skinned with jwplayer, and code rendered in a jQuery().dialog() then get the correct jwplayer funct? (I know about the local security sandbox issues and have added localhost to my trusted sites. Also, same problem on http live site.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it [grumble grumble]. Just needed to add a $(document).ready(). Seems to be more important for the swf fallback than for the html5 supporting browsers.